# Check if ads:testdevice is working properly?

Tags: android, admob

I put this in my LinearLayout

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="d7fd8f9ghf042k4"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="34HF70000000G501" />
```

I'm still testing my application, but when I checked my AdMob account, I found out this:

[image]

I don't understand, what's happening? Am I getting revenue for clicking my own Ads?
If Yes, how could this happen when I have mentioned this line `ads:testDevices="34HF70000000G501"` in my XML layout?

Answer (score 1):

The ID you put inside of `ads:testDevices` needs to be the hashed device ID which is output in LogCat when you load an ad request on the device. It does not work if you use your actual device id.

Comment: Yes, this is the one I exactly used, the one I saw in the LogCat. However, what I'm asking is IF is it normal to get revenue for my own clicks even if I have PUT ads:testDevices="blablablad3242sfs" ?

Comment: You should not get revenue if you click on test ads. It's more likely that for some reason you aren't getting test ads.

Comment: so any idea why i'm not being able to make those test ads?

Comment: Well for one thing the test devices should be 32 hexadecimal characters, so the ID you have above won't work. I'm not sure if you just put in a dummy value there though.